# XMLHttpRequest cannot load file from android asset folder on emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, hybrid-mobile-app

I am new to hybrid development. I wrote a small application which launches webview. I have XML, JS files copied in /asset folder.

App works fine on my samsung tablet but I get following errors on emulator

> 05-30 06:09:07.080: I/chromium(1245): [INFO:CONSOLE(0)]
>   "XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   file:///android_asset/resource/service_config.xml. Cross origin
>   requests are only supported for HTTP.", source:
>   file:///android_asset/Startup.html (0)

I got to know it happens due to chrome browsers security model and android webview too uses the same component as chrome browser. But all these largely related to chrome browser not addressing the issue on emulator.

Appreciate any help on this issue.

Thanks,
iuq

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android WebView throws "cross origin requests are only supported for http" exception while trying to load resource from disk](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25439619/android-webview-throws-cross-origin-requests-are-only-supported-for-http-excep)

Answer (score 20):

got the same error. I fixed it by changing some settings of the webview in the activities `onCreate()` method as follows:

```
// settings for webview
mWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
mWebView.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
mWebView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
mWebView.getSettings().setAllowContentAccess(true);
mWebView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
mWebView.getSettings().setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);

//load file
mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
```

Hope that might help you :)

Comment: Thanks, this solved my issue. Just to note that in API18 this was not necessary, but it is in API20.

Comment: Richard R - High5 --> you saved my a massive headache