# Android WebView throws "cross origin requests are only supported for http" exception while trying to load resource from disk

Tags: android, webview

i have developed a single page game in html/js and am trying to host it inside an android webview. i have a folder `src/main/assets/www/` and this line of code to bootstrap my app:

```
mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
```

the `index.html` loads a `app.js` file which is my game. when i try to make an `xhr` request from within `app.js` to get `assets/myimage.svg` (physical location `src/main/assets/www/assets/myimage.svg`) :

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('get', 'assets/myimage.svg', true);
        xhr.send();
```

I get this error: `cross origin requests are only supported for http`. why is this a cross-origin request? what can i do to fix this? i cannot host the svg on a http webserver and cannot inline it in `app.js` - it has to be loaded from disk.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Not sure but you can try these steps and see if it helps:

a) Initialize your WebView:

b) get WebView settings:

```
WebSettings settings = _webView.getSettings();
```

c) set following settings:

```
settings.setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
settings.setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
```

d) now you can load your your html file by standard way:

```
mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
```

e) Don't forget to add the internet permission in your manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Comment: there is no need for <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

Comment: According to docs (SDK 21) the call to setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs is not relevant in your example.  "Note that the value of this setting is ignored if the value of getAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs is true."

Comment: There is no setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs & setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs!!!! only setAllowFileAccess.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Saved me a lot of time.

Comment: I'm having same issue, but on IOS. do you have any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 4):

If you are looking for the same problem with Android, but using Xamarin/C#

```
        var webView = FindViewById<WebView>(Resource.Id.webView);
        webView.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
        webView.Settings.AllowFileAccessFromFileURLs = true;
        webView.Settings.AllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs = true;

        webView.LoadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
```