# Use Font-face in Android WebView

Tags: android, html, css, webview, fonts

I want insert font-face in my WebView for display few specials fonts on different WebSite.

For example in Wikipedia i want i use a bit of code for change the font in the html, when this is done, i show the page and the font are not Century Gothic like in the html code. When i try on Google Chrome don't work too. When i try with :

```
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(...)
```

it work if i put on header :

```
"<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='file:///android_asset/style.css'/>"
```

In my style.css :

```
@font-face {
    font-family: Andika;
    src: url('fonts/Andika.ttf');
}
@font-face {
    font-family: Calibri;
    src: url('fonts/Calibri.ttf');
}
@font-face {
    font-family: Century Gothic;
    src: url('fonts/CenturyGothic.ttf');
}
@font-face {
    font-family: Comic Sans MS;
    src: url('fonts/ComicSansMS.ttf');
}

@font-face {
    font-family: Lexia;
    src: url('fonts/Lexia.ttf');
}
@font-face {
    font-family: Lucida Sans Unicode;
    src: url('fonts/LucidaSansUnicode.ttf');
}
@font-face {
    font-family: Tahoma;
    src: url('fonts/Tahoma.ttf');
}
@font-face {
    font-family: Tiresias;
    src: url('fonts/Tiresias.ttf');
}
@font-face {
    font-family: Trebuchet MS;
    src: url('fonts/TrebuchetMS.ttf');
}
@font-face {
    font-family: Verdana;
    src: url('fonts/Verdana.ttf');
}
```

But it is on local data.

I want make that with external page like Wikipedia.

When i inject the link on the wikipedia html page i have this error message :

```
Not allowed to load local resource: file:///android_asset/
```

And if i put directly the `@font-face` in style field i have the same error.

SomeOne have an idea for resolve this mistake ?

Please!

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

1. Use any HTTP client to fetch HTML of Wikipedia's page
2. Use JSoup to parse it and insert your `<link...` tag inside it
3. Load it using `loadDataWithBaseURL` in your `WebView`

Comment: i try that but i loose all images and links ...but it works, but the page is not functional...

Comment: Oh that happens because you change the base URL, if you can host your fonts elsewhere, then this might work.

Comment: I try to host the style.css and fonts on my website and i have others errors : `Font from origin 'http://maximelimone.fr' has been blocked from loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`...

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25439619/android-webview-throws-cross-origin-requests-are-only-supported-for-http-excep)

Comment: Don't work i have the same error. I believed... Thank you