# xml httprequest cannot load in android webView although it is from url

Tags: android, xmlhttprequest, android-webview

```
 webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
            WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
            webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            webSettings.setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
            webSettings.setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
            webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
            webView.loadData(html, mime, encoding);
```

although i am providing url
i get "XMLHttpRequest cannot load . Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, https.", source: data:text/html,

Comment: here it is it is from my web server

Comment: 'http://www.petition-cic.com" and there is http://

Comment: Try adding "http://" or "https://" before the string link and you will get rid of that error.

Comment: already has but still get that error

Comment: "XMLHttpRequest cannot load . Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, https.", source: data:text/html,<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.petition-cic.com/

Comment: post your webview code by editing question

Comment: Try coding in java calling loadUrl() method of webView class with setJavascriptEnabled() method?

Comment: this html variable contains the html i received to draw the form

Comment: what is mime value? and encoding? You checked if that encoding is supported?

Comment: here it is String mime = "text/html";
    String encoding = "utf-8";

Comment: Yes it is correct although, try "UTF-8" if its case sensitive. I will get back to you if I found something.

Comment: Did you see this? [SOF Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25439619/android-webview-throws-cross-origin-requests-are-only-supported-for-http-excep).

Comment: yeah i tried and it give me an error that i can't load from local

Comment: Were you able to solve this issue?