# Allow file:// request in react-native Webview

Tags: android-webview, react-native

I am trying to use readiumjs viewer in a react-native webview.

https://github.com/readium/readium-js-viewer

Basically it's an HTML page loading dynamically an epub file. Doesn't seem to work on Android.
I found out that the problem is the request to load the epub is made throught a "file://xxx" uri.
And the webview is blocking it because of his cross-origin request policy.

How can I manage to allow request to file:// ?

I found this for basic Android : [Android WebView throws "cross origin requests are only supported for http" exception while trying to load resource from disk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25439619/android-webview-throws-cross-origin-requests-are-only-supported-for-http-excep)
Is there an equivalent with React-native ?

Answer (score 0):

finally I find out that:

https://github.com/lucasferreira/react-native-webview-android

create webview component that allow cross-orignin request to file:///

so it solve my problem.

Comment: Hi, I am have the same problem you asked here. As what you do, I am trying to use RN with Webview to display a PDF file. Inside the webview, I need a file object to make it work, I guess you faced the same problem. How do you convert a file path in RN to a file object in Webview? Thanks

Comment: @Erwin.H Hello can you be more precise, " inside the webview, i need a file object to make it work" ?    do you want to call the pdf inside the webview with http request   ? maybe [link](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/1442) could help ?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I want to get the file object, just like what you got when using <input type=file>, instead of an url. After searching around, I think this maybe possible. Transfer the file in React Native side into Base64 code and then pass it as a string to WebView, then in WebView side parse it back to a file object. I am still working on it. Hope it works.