# How do I display a simple Three JS webpage using Android WebView?

Tags: android, three.js, android-webview, webgl

I am trying to display a simple three.js webpage on my Android device. This is what I've tried till now:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Context context;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    context = this;

    WebView webView = findViewById(R.id.modelWebView);

    WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
    webSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
    webSettings.setAllowContentAccess(true);
    webSettings.setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
    webSettings.setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);

    webView.loadUrl("https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_animation_cloth");

}
}
```

Logcat:

```
2021-08-05 22:20:46.046 19796-19878/com.mindstix.testarchitect E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000088ef
2021-08-05 22:20:46.047 19796-19878/com.mindstix.testarchitect E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000088ef
2021-08-05 22:20:46.581 19796-19796/com.mindstix.testarchitect I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(54)] "Unrecognized feature: 'xr-spatial-tracking'.", source: https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_animation_cloth (54)
2021-08-05 22:20:46.804 19796-19826/com.mindstix.testarchitect E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000088ef
2021-08-05 22:20:46.804 19796-19826/com.mindstix.testarchitect E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000088ef
.
.
.
.
2021-08-05 22:20:49.028 19796-19878/com.mindstix.testarchitect E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000088ef
2021-08-05 22:20:49.029 19796-19878/com.mindstix.testarchitect E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000088ef
2021-08-05 22:20:49.034 19796-19878/com.mindstix.testarchitect E/chromium: [ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder_autogen.h(1648)] [.WebGL-0xc85e0800]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_ENUM : GetIntegerv: <- error from previous GL command
2021-08-05 22:20:49.038 19796-19878/com.mindstix.testarchitect E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000088ef
2021-08-05 22:20:49.078 19796-19878/com.mindstix.testarchitect I/chatty: uid=10135(com.mindstix.testarchitect) Chrome_InProcGp identical 6 lines
2021-08-05 22:20:49.079 19796-19878/com.mindstix.testarchitect E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000088ef
2021-08-05 22:20:49.870 19796-19796/com.mindstix.testarchitect I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "[.WebGL-0xc85e0800]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_ENUM : GetIntegerv: <- error from previous GL command", source: https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_animation_cloth.html (0)
```

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong. Please suggest how to proceed.

Comment: What is the error / issue?

Comment: Nothing is displayed on the webview when I run the app. Normal websites load but ones with three js don't load. I also tried running it on an android device instead of a emulator but it still does not work.

Comment: Any errors in logcat?

Comment: Added logcat. the dots are just another ~20 lines of "E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param".

Comment: Check if any of these works,
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49136748/how-do-you-implement-three-js-code-into-an-android-mobile-application

Comment: It gives me an error for the undefined variable "passedImpactMobile". Could you please tell me what it is? Do I need to import some libraries for it?